# Definition of previsible processes?

Tags: probability-theory

Definition from my textbook:

> A stochastic process $X = (X_n, n \in \mathbb{N}_0)$ is called *predictable* (or *previsible*) with respect to the filtration $\mathbb{F} = (\mathcal{F}_n, n \in \mathbb{N}_0 )$ if $X_0$ is constant and if, for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ 
>   $$X_n \text{ is } \mathcal{F}_{n-1}\text{-measurable.}$$

Okay, but that surely cannot mean that I can really ***predict*** the next outcome $X_{n+1}$ if I know $X_0, \ldots, X_n$ (regardless if $X$ is also adapted to $\mathbb{F}$), right?

Comment: No you cannot, rather this means that one can predict the next outcome $X_{n+1}$ if one knows $\mathcal{F}_n$ (and there is usually more information in this than just $X_0$, ..., $X_n$).

Comment: I agree with @Did. An easy example for a filtration $\mathcal{F}_n$ which contains more information than $X_0,\ldots,X_n$ is $\mathcal{F}_n := \mathcal{A}$ where $\mathcal{A}$ denotes the $\sigma$-algebra on the probability space $\Omega$.

Comment: Somehow I'm interested in the notion @Did mentioned. How can conditioning on the filtration and conditioning on the sample path differ? I guess conditioning on $X_{1} = x_{1},X_2 = x_2, \ldots, X_n = x_n$ is the same thing with conditioning on $\mathcal{F}_n = \sigma(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$, no? What is the alternative filtration which can cause the case mentioned above?

Comment: @oeda Post this as a question on the site then.

Comment: OK, it will also help me to make sense of the question.

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear -mathematically speaking- what do you mean by *predict*, but in a certain way, you *can* predict $X_n$ by knowing $ \mathcal{F}_{n-1} $ (which may be the same as knowing $X_0,X_1,...,X_{n-1}$ if $\mathcal{F}_n$ is the natural filtration).

The thing is, in applications, a previsible process has to do with a *strategy* (i.e. a decision you make taking into account the previous information, for example a gambling strategy) rather than with a system you are analysing.

See for example *Probablity with Martingales* , by Williams.

I'm sorry if this answer arrives late!

Comment: Am I right to think that a for a previsable process, one can in some sense estimate $X_{n}$ without having to taking avarages of values with some subsets. One can estimate it just as the immediate predecessor.

Comment: Mmm I don't think so, that sounds to me as a Martingale!!

Comment: hmm if we have a martingale then one takes the avarages of $X_{n}$ over the sets in $F_{n-1}$ which in turn have the same distriution as $X_{n-1}$. In this case this we dont take avarages but get the possible values and thier probabilites just by looking at the predecessor $X_{n-1}$ to get the value of $X_{n}$. Or have I slipped somewhere?

Comment: You are right about the averages. On the other hand, take the trivial previsible (deterministic) process  $X_n =n$. In which sense you estimate $X_{n+1}$ as $X_n$ ?

Comment: Right, I was thinking that $C_{n}$ was a martingale aswell...So it more like "if we know what event in $\mathcal{F}_{n-1}$ did occur then we know the value of $X_{n}$?

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you can always predict in terms of the best available information but you will NOT necessarily know the value of $X_{n+1}$ if you know the values of $X_0, \ldots, X_n$. This is easy to show since based on the definition of a previsible process, if you are at $(n-1)^{th}$ index of the filtration (i.e. $\mathcal{F}_{n-1}$), you already know the values of $X_0, \ldots, X_n$ but you don't get to know the value of $X_{n+1}$. You will know $X_{n+1}$ when you are at $n^{th}$ index of filtration (i.e. $\mathcal{F}_{n}$). 
I think in the question there seems to be a confusion regarding what subscript $n$ means in $X_n$. It doesn't mean when you know $X_0, \ldots, X_n$ you are at index $n$ in the filtration. In fact, you know those values when you are at $\mathcal{F}_{n-1}$ which doesn't tell what $X_{n+1}$ is.